# Convert T-SQL to Lambda

Tags: lambda, expression

**how to convert this query to lambda expression**

```
SELECT *
FROM   T1
WHERE  T1.a = 21
       AND T1.b = 1
       AND T1.c = 0
       AND (T1.d IN (SELECT T2.a
                     FROM   T2
                     WHERE  T2.b = 21
                            AND T2.c = 10251367
                            AND T2.d = 100001000002)
            OR T1.d IN (SELECT (T2.a / 100) * 100
                        FROM   T2
                        WHERE  T2.b = 21
                               AND T2.c = 10251367
                               AND T2.d = 100001000002))
```

thanks

Comment: SELECT (T2.a / 100) * 100 ?
Apart from that, the two subqueries (T1.d IN ...) look pretty the same to me. What have you tried so far? No Joins, only conditions. Should be pretty forward!

Comment: the field is return values ((T2.a / 100) * 100) from select for IN operation

Answer (score 0):

Two different ways, one is linq to sql and the other uses extension methods.
Like Matten pointed out `Select t2a` is logical the same as `SELECT (t2.a /100) * 100)`

ALL BELOW IS PSEUDO CODE SO DO NOT CUT AND PASTE AND EXPECT IT TO WORK.

Linq to Sql

```
var firstQuery = (From a in context.T2
                     WHERE a.b == 21 AND a.c == 10251367 AND a.d == 100001000002)   


var final = (FROM foo IN context.T1
             where foo.a == 21 
             AND FOO.B == 1 
             AND FOO.C == 0
             and firstQuery.contains(foo.d)
```

Extension methods

```
var firstQuery = context.T2.Select.Where( a => a.b == 21 AND a.c == 10251367 AND a.d == 100001000002 )           

var final = context.T1.Select(y => y).Where ( x= > x. a== 21 && x.b = 1 && x.c == 0 and x.d firstQuery.contains(x.d));
```

Comment: I'd also suggest to call '.ToList()' or '.ToArray()' on the 'firstQuery' enumerable in order to achieve a better performance when the database queries are not performed on the database, otherwise the 'firstQuery' would possibly be enumerated more than once.

Comment: @Matten, That is a good point but, I believe the firstQuery.contains will be executed on the database server. If you materialize the queries all the data will be parsed on the our app server instead of our database server.

Comment: I want all the commands in a block to be performed and the result returned by a query.
Table T2 should be reviewed in two forms mentioned in the example T-SQL Complete

Comment: @mohammed, the queries I generated are logically equivalent to your query. your subQueries are the same. What they evaulate out to is ` AND (X = Y OR X = Y)`. Can you explain how your subquries differ?